# WordPress Pass variable to another shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress

I have multiple plugins from different developers, which allow me to display Amazon products.
They all require me to enter the amazon category ID, inside of their shortcodes.

```
[amazon bestseller="1234567"]
[amz_links node="1234567"]
[amazon_toprated category="1234567"]
```

I am using these shortcodes across a huge amount of pages, widgets etc.
Every now and then I need to change the IDs, and it's a HUGE hassle to manually change them all.

My idea was to create my own shortcode, such as `[myamazon_id]` and enter that shortcode inside the other shortcodes: `[amazon bestseller="[myamazon_id]"]`

Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work, since those are self enclosed shortcodes, which apperantly don't allow for shortcodes inside of shortcodes.

My current solution is to use a plugin that allows me to use PHP inside of WordPress pages and widgets.

`[insert_php]echo do_shortcode( '[amazon bestseller="'.myamazonid().'"]' );[/insert_php]`

This does work, but I am wondering if there is a nicer solution to pass a varible to a shortcode. Using PHP directly on the pages and widgets is really not something I feel good about.

My goal would be to have something like this: `[amazon bestseller="[myamazon_id]"]`

Answer (score 0):

One simple solution for this can be the Plugin [Post Snippets](https://wordpress.org/plugins/post-snippets/). Whit this plugin you can create 3 new shortcodes which contains the 3 amazon shortcodes with the category ID. Now you can use the new created shortcodes, and if you want to change the category ID, you just have to edit this at one place.

Answer (score 0):

Shortcode with like this `[amazon bestseller="myamazon_id"]` possbile with following code.

You do not need to wrap another shortcode with these braces `"["` and `"]"`

```
function first_shortcode_amazon( $atts ) {
    $newvar = do_shortcode('['.$atts['bestseller'].']');
    return $newvar;
}
add_shortcode( 'amazon', 'first_shortcode_amazon' );


function second_shortcode_for_amazonid( $atts ) {
    global $post;
    // here i have placed global post id. you can do code to get amazon id here
    return 'AMAZON_ID=> '.$post->ID;
}
add_shortcode( 'myamazon_id', 'second_shortcode_for_amazonid' );
```

Comment: This looks like a good solution, but I can't get it to work. The shortcode is acting like no ID was supplied, which leads me to believe the ```first_shortcode_amazon``` function doesn't parse ```myamazon_id``` as a shortcode, but instead as normal text.

Answer (score 0):

First, you will have to define $atts item in your function because $atts is an array.

Here is the complete code to pass the variable in shortcode -

Let's suppose you need to show all the product of a category through shortcode, You need to do following code in your function file -

```
     function creative_writing_func($atts) {
     $args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'product',
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'product_cat'    => $atts['categoryname']
);

$loop = new WP_Query( $args );

while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
    global $product;
    echo '<br /><a href="'.get_permalink().'">' . woocommerce_get_product_thumbnail().' '.get_the_title().'</a>';
endwhile;

wp_reset_query();
}

add_shortcode('creative_writing_func_short', 'creative_writing_func');
```

Now you can simply paste the shortcode code in your template file or Wordpress default editor -

```
[creative_writing_func_short categoryname="creative-writing-english-literature"]
```

Where we're passing the Category name (creative-writing-english-literature) in the shortcode.

Have tested it and it's working.